# Restful api structure

Tags: api, rest

Simply, what's better?

**API Methods:**

```
GET videos/getall
GET videos/get?id=1

GET news/getall
GET news/get/?id=1

GET blogs/getall
GET blogs/get?id=1
```

**OR**

```
GET content/getall/?type=videos
GET content/getall/?type=news
GET content/get?id=1&type=blogs
```

First way isn't look like DRY. But it has some advatanges. So what way is better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of these URIs are wrong. They include action information(i.e. getall and get) which turns your URIs into regular RPC calls.

You can choose simpler approach:

```
GET /videos
GET /videos/1

GET /news
GET /news/1

GET /blogs
GET /blogs/1
```

HTTP GET already means that you are retrieving data.

Comment: I got it. But i wanted to ask what way is better? Create three methods for `videos`, `news` and `blogs` or use one method and `content_type` parameter?

Comment: Neither, you must use http method + resource identifier and bind this information to your callback function/method, URI implies "type" information and you can use it as you like. This depends on the platform you are using for implementation. In .net or JEE you can use annotations.